# Finding the linear transformation of a vector given other vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let $\Phi : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be the linear transformation that takes $\textbf{v}_1 = [1, 1]$ to $[1, 0]$ and $\textbf{v}_2 = [1, 2]$ to $[0, 1]$.

Find $\Phi(\textbf{e}_1)$.

I'm aware that I'm supposed to find a linear combination of the vectors to get the vector $\textbf{e}_1$ which can then be transformed. Now sure exactly how to get there though. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Solve the system $x\mathbf{v_1} + y\mathbf{v_2} = \mathbf{e_1}$, i.e.
$$\begin{align}
   x + y &= 1 \\
   x + 2y &= 0
   \end{align}
$$

So we have $2\mathbf{v_1} - \mathbf{v_2} = \mathbf{e_1}$, and 
$$\Phi(\mathbf{e_1}) = \Phi(2\mathbf{v_1} - \mathbf{v_2}) = 2\Phi(\mathbf{v_1}) - \Phi(\mathbf{v_2}) = 2\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}2 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}.$$